# How to get pid of su --session-command file thats ran on there

Tags: su, pid, pidfile

This line ran in a script

```
su --session-command="$javaCommandLine & >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile" $serviceUser || return 1
pid="$(<$pidFile)"
echo $pid
```

The Pid is increased by one from the Pid the program ran by su really is.
How I do I get that program's pid?

Comment: Please, don't cross-post. Since you have an accepted answer on SF, you should remove this Q.

Comment: Is it in the terms of service that I can't post the same question on 2 different forums? even though they are connected. Do you own the site or you are just a asshole trying to control people for no reason. If I post on both forums, which  both have linux questions and they are both in a way server related, posting on both gets you more answers for free and more people look at them. So whats wrong about doing that? (they are both worded differently anyways).

Comment: What you did is IMHO cross-posting, which is not very appreciated here. Please see [this Meta Stack Overflow question which is about cross-posting.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) And please try to be more polite, I'm not harassing you in any way, I'm just trying to be polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a answer from serverfault stackexchange. by `Daniel t.` @ https://serverfault.com/questions/563087/sh-bash-script-ambiguous-redirect-pid-of-file-using-single-quotes

Quoted:

> The process ID is off by one because you have put an extra `&` after
>   the `$javaCommandLine`. In other words, you have put two processes in
>   the background before calling `echo $!`, thus getting the PID of
>   `>>$serviceLogFile 2>&1` rather than `$javaCommandLine`. Those two
>   pieces should be put in one, as the old 2 line codes shows
>
> ```
>  su --session-command="$javaCommandLine & >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile" $serviceUser || return 1
> ```
>
> You might need to change it to -
>
> ```
>  su --session-command="$javaCommandLine >>$serviceLogFile 2>&1 & echo \$! >$pidFile" $serviceUser || return 1
> ```